# File sharing between RHEL 5 and Windows 7

Tags: linux, rhel, samba

I am trying to setup the **SAMBA** service to share file between *RHEL 5* and *Windows 7*. I have both the operating systems in the same machine. I tried to setup as discussed in [this](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Sharing_Files_Between_RHEL_5_and_Windows_Systems_with_Samba) link. I checked the workgroup name and it was **WORKGROUP** in *Windows 7*. I had setup the server preference as in the below screenshot.

[image]

I clicked on "**Add share**" button and am trying to share a small PDF file to the *Windows 7*. However, when I go to *Windows 7* and check the network and sharing center, I do not see the shared file present there. Is there any other step that I am missing?

Comment: The above tool just configures Samba, have you verified the samba service is actually running? Also, RHEL5 has two versions of Samba. `samba` is Samba 3.0 whereas `samba3x` is Samba 3.5. The latter is much more reliable, I would recommend ensuring that you're using the `samba3x` service, it is running, and there aren't any firewall rules blocking samba.

Comment: Until you get it working, I'd also do a `setenforce 0` to switch SELinux into permissive mode so that becomes one less thing to figure out.

Comment: I added the firewall rule to allow samba sharing and also I verified the SAMBA service is running by using the command, service /sbin/smb/ start..It started and loaded OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are running Windows or RHEL5 in a virtual machine this will not work. As soon as you shutdown your computer to boot into you're Windows image the Samba service stops.

What you can do is create a third partition that Windows will recognize and that Linux can mount. Step by instructions here: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/35807/how-to-harmonize-your-dual-boot-setup-for-windows-and-ubuntu/